# How to update binding or remove earlier binding in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have following code to get the data from ajax call and bind with different sections of my page.

```
$.getJSON("api/RedeemProduct", { 'productId': productId }, function (data) {
    categoryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data[0].WishlistProduct.WishlistCategory);
    ko.applyBindings(categoryViewModel, $('section.intro').get(0));

    activityTypesViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(activityTypesViewModel, $('.categories-gallery .frame').get(0));

    activeActivityViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS($('.categories-gallery .frame .category.active').data('wishlist-activity'));
    ko.applyBindings(activeActivityViewModel, $('#details-box').get(0));
```

See the first line in the code , I am getting data of a particular product. Next time if I use the same code to bind the data of different product, binding is not being updated rather same product is added multiple time because of calling ko.applyBindings()

What should I do to remove the old bindings and binding the new data with the sections?

Answer (score 8):

Stop using `ko.applyBindings` more than once. I feel like this needs to go in the tag wiki.

Never, ever do this.

Call `ko.applyBindings` once (per element, if that's how you are doing this, but still *once*). After that, updating your viewmodel will automatically update the bound elements. That's the *entire point* of the binding.

Comment: I am calling the ko.applyBindings on document load only and now only updating the model from the ajax data but page is data is still not updated.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, perhaps in a fiddle. "Its doesn't update" isn't enough to troubleshoot on

Comment: This question is asked a lot, presumably because knockout.js is too freaking hard to figure out / debug. I suppose the choice then is to a) Stop using knockout.js, and b) if you stick with knockout.js, then do it right.

Comment: @HamishGrubijan I guess you could blame Knockout, but I don't think that's fair. If this guy had gone through the tutorials on the site, he would have known he was doing this incorrectly. No matter how simple a tool is to use, there is a way to use it incorrectly. It's not a reflection on the screwdriver that people pick it up and use it like a hammer.

Comment: Tyrsius, I am that guy as well. I went through the tutorial, spend one day trying to get certain events to fire (in a large project, not a single label with button example), then said screw it and did it with a couple of lines in jQuery instead - updating DOM manually instead of trying to modify part of an observable inside of an array. I cannot think of a good way to debug the knockout library and thus I am not keen on learning it. The JS/jQuery stuff - I have a debugger and a "REPL" for that right in the browser.

Comment: @HamishGrubijan There are ways to debug that, but if you are jumping straight into a large project without knowing the basics then I still think you are going to have problems, regardless of the framework/library. If you have something specific, ask a question on SO and people can help you. But again, doing complex things with no foundational knowledge and no experience, and then blaming the tool for your difficulty seems a bit... immature.

Comment: Unhelpful, so how do you figure out which element you supposedly called applybindings on twice? If you load ajax in then applybindings to it, when you remove that dom node and replace that part of your webpage with a different screen, SPA style, it is a nightmare to figure out what node KO thinks is still bound.

Comment: @pilavdzice it really isn't. Put a breakpoint [right here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src%2Fbinding%2FbindingAttributeSyntax.js#L279), the `node` is accessible as a parameter. Easy as pie.

Comment: I agree, that's what you have to do. So downloading the unminified source and and digging into debugging a core library is your idea of 'easy as pie'? That is my definition of a vague and useless nightmare error message that wastes my time.

Comment: 'look in the source to figure out what the error message is telling you' = poor usability

Comment: If you don't want to debug you could always look at the stack trace in the console. I don't know how you expect dynamic content in *any* framework to reported to you any better. Why are you manually removing DOM nodes and replace parts of your page? That's exactly what Knockout is for; when Knockout does that, it handles the unbinding for you. The only way to get this error is to try and work around the framework; you can't really blame the framework for usability problems that come not using the framework properly.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, I have to call

```
ko.mapping.fromJs
```

and pass the `newdata` and `viewmodel` which needs to be updated like

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data[0].WishlistProduct.WishlistCategory, categoryViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) from the Knockout.js official page addressing this very issue.

In short, you should call `applyBindings()` (for a given page section) only once and when retrieving the updated data, you should just update the observable view model with the new data like this

```
var updatedCategoryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data[0].WishlistProduct.WishlistCategory);
categoryViewModel(updatedCategoryViewModel);
```

Comment: I have removed the apply Bindings and now just updating model but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help someone, Knockout have been a journey for me and a mind breaking model.

I needed to load more or less stuff when a button was clicked so at first I thought this would help me, this was my first approach:

```
var Task = function(name, description) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);  
    this.description = ko.observable(description);      

}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray();

    self.clearTask = function(data, event) {

           self.tasks.remove(data);   

    };
    self.addTask = function() {
        var task = new Task("new", "");        
        self.tasks.push(task);
    };
    self.addTask2 = function (name, description)
    {
        var task = new Task(name, description);        
        self.tasks.push(task);
    }

};
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.addTask2("Dog Food","description");
ko.applyBindings(vm);

function ClickedMoreItems()
{
    vm = new ViewModel()
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food2","description");
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food3","description");    

}
function ClickedLessItems()
{
    vm = new ViewModel()
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food4","description");        

}
```

Once I hit ClickedMoreItems() nothing happened. So I decided to use again in each function `ko.applyBindings(vm);` and it kind of worked. But when i hit ClickedLessItems "Dog Food4" was replicated twice.

```
function ClickedMoreItems()
    {
        vm.Clear();
        vm.addTask2("Dog Food2","description");
        vm.addTask2("Dog Food3","description");    
        ko.applyBindings(vm);        
    }
    function ClickedLessItems()
    {
        vm.Clear();
        vm.addTask2("Dog Food4","description");  
        ko.applyBindings(vm);        
    }
```

So I decided to do this and it make it work:

1. Use `ko.applyBindings(vm);` just at the start as Tyrsius recommended.
2. Create a clear function

So the final code is this:

```
var Task = function(name, description) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);  
    this.description = ko.observable(description);                
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray();

    self.clearTask = function(data, event) {

           self.tasks.remove(data);   

    };
    self.addTask = function() {
        var task = new Task("new", "");        
        self.tasks.push(task);
    };
    self.addTask2 = function (name, description)
    {
        var task = new Task(name, description);        
        self.tasks.push(task);
    }
    self.Clear = function()
    {
        self.tasks.removeAll();
    }
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.addTask2("Dog Food","description");
ko.applyBindings(vm);

function ClickedMoreItems()
{
    vm.Clear();
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food2","description");
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food3","description");    

}
function ClickedLessItems()
{
    vm.Clear();
    vm.addTask2("Dog Food4","description");  

}
```

You can see code in action [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9B2/398/)

Answer (score -1):

To remove binding use ko.cleanNode(element)